# How to prevent a notification to re-launch an Activity

Tags: android, notifications

I have the following piece of code:

```
public void notify(int notificationId, int iconId, String message, Class<?> returnTo, boolean onGoing, boolean showTime, boolean autoCancel)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, returnTo);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(mContext);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(returnTo);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

    PendingIntent pending = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    mNotificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Notification")
                        .setContentText(message)
                        .setSmallIcon(iconId)
                        .setContentIntent(pending)
                        .setAutoCancel(autoCancel);

    if (!showTime)
    {
        mNotificationBuilder.setWhen(0);
    }

    Notification notification = mNotificationBuilder.build();

    if (onGoing)
    {
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    }

    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_TAG, notificationId, notification);
}
```

Which works perfectly to create a notification.

However, the Activity that called this function (i.e. the `Class<?> returnTo` parameter) is started for a second time, instead of returning to the initial instance, when the notification is pressed.

To try to circumvent this, I've added the flags `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` & `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` to the Intent I create at the top of the function. Sadly, this didn't work, so I tried something else.

I added `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to the Activity that is calling this code, to see if that would help. But sadly, this didn't work either.

I've tried finding anything on Google, but all that comes up with are the flags (which, as mentioned, I've already tried) and the launchMode (as mentioned, also tried).

So, are there any other flags, settings, etc. that I can try?

### Edit:

There seems to be a bit of text on `android:launchMode="singleTop"` over on the Android Developers site ([link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)).

This states:

`In other circumstances — for example, if an existing instance of the "singleTop" activity is in the target task, but not at the top of the stack, or if it's at the top of a stack, but not in the target task — a new instance would be created and pushed on the stack.`

Could it be possible that there is an issue with using `TaskStackBuilder` to get my `PendingIntent`, with regards to `or if it's at the top of a stack, but not in the target task`?

Comment: Have you tried `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`

Comment: Yes, that didn't make a difference.

Comment: Strange? This is the description of `singleInstance` from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode): _Same as "singleTask", except that the system doesn't launch any other activities into the task holding the instance. The activity is always the single and only member of its task._ Which means you cannot have more than one instance of the same activity in the stack. How are you launching your notification?

Comment: This function is in a helper class. This helper class gets the Context from Activity where I create an instance. From this Activity (currently my main Activity) I am creating a notification by a simple call to this method (and removing it when that Activity is closed).

Comment: Do you declare your activities with the `android:launchMode="singleTask"` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`? Or, how are you defining the activities in your manifest? What you declared in `AndroidManifest.xml` can affect how Android launch activities from notification.

Comment: I added the line `android:launchMode="singleTask"` to the Activity declaration in my AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: I posted an answer below (comment field is limited so cannot post as a comment). Just change the parameters to include `Class<?> returnTo`, like what you have, instead of the hard-coded `MainActivity.class` shown in the example. Try it and let me know how you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected in my Edit, it was the `TaskStackBuilder` that was the culprit.

I changed my code from:

```
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(mContext);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(returnTo);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
```

to:

```
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

After this, the notification behaves the way I want it to.

Comment: but this will wreck navigation process

Comment: What about navigation process?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static void showNotification(Context context, String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    // Ensures navigating back to activity, then to Home screen.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    // Add the activity parent chain to the stack builder.
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    // Add a new Intent to the task stack.
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);     
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    // Create notification.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) { // API 16 onwards
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifier)
            .setTicker(message)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(message)) 
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_DEFAULT, builder.build());         
    } else {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifier)
            .setTicker(message)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_DEFAULT, builder.build());         
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I can see is that you use `Notification.Builder` instead of `NotificationCompat.Builder` when the SDK version is higher than ICS, right?

Comment: Correct. `Notification.Builder` is supported internally in the firmware from API level 16 onwards.

Comment: Switching to `Notification.Builder` also doesn't help. :(

Comment: Well, I guess you may have to log a bug with Google as I'm running out of ideas to help you. Sorry.

Comment: I fixed it, see my own answer. ;) Thanks for your time and effort though.

Comment: No worries. Glad you fixed it yourself. Although it's a bit strange my answer didn't work for you. The answer I posted also exist in my Android apps and it works for me. Oh, well...